# What does 'Rebuild Permissions' actually do?

Tags: nodes, users

I've been working with a lot of custom content types lately, and I keep getting a message to rebuild my permissions.

It seems like it happens everytime I create a new content type. Is this normal behavior? And what exactly is happening when I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Drupal core uses database tables to control some aspects of content viewing/editing permissions. These tables are used by contrib modules like Domain Access or Taxonomy Access Control to store information about which roles/users can see which nodes. Because it is not easily determinable which configuration changes will result in actual permission changes Drupal marks these tables as needing updating for a broad set of configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal, permissions are saved in node_access table. Based on key/value pair in node access table, permissions are restricted to users.

When you use any content access modules like (Organic groups, Access by Term), permissions for each node will be rebuilt on node access table based on configuration.

So when a new content type is created, it is needed for those modules to rebuilt new permissions for the newly created content type

In general, rebuild permission will call [node_access_rebuild](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access_rebuild/7) function. Check that function for more info.